# How can I fetch a url from a browser to my java code?

Tags: java, sdk, oauth-2.0, box

I am trying to implement the OAuth 2 authentication into my java code for Box(Cloud Storage Service). The OAuth 2 implementation code is taken from  [OAuth 2 essentials](https://github.com/dmfs/oauth2-essentials).

As you know, the oAuth has two phases. First phase requires that the client make a http GET or POST request to [this link](https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize) also sending some client credentials along with it. So I open a browser with the above url from inside my java code(Main.java) using this piece of code:

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
    {
         Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(authorizationUrl.toString()));
    }
```

1. In the browser I can see the web page where the client has to provide email and password to grant access to my app. All goes well and after granting access the browser is redirected to the redirect_uri provided by me which is a java servlet class in my localhost(I don't know if servlet is really necessary for this process but i'm using it).
2. This redirect_uri is now extended from the one I provided because it has the code and state parameters provided by the server. (note: this part of the scene is happening in a browser while my Main.java which invoked the browser is still running and waiting for the exteded redirect_uri which i have to feed it)

So how do I feed the the extended redirect_uri from the browser(or the servlet class) to the Main.java class which has invoked the browser on the first leg of the oauth process.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this is Main application

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(authorizationUrl.toString()));
}
```

Why don't you call a servlet to do redirection to https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize with required parameters and then send back the code and state.

Write the logic for handling OAuth in a servlet and using [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) call the servlet from your main application. Return the code and state to main application from the servlet after OAuth completes.

Comment: nice! I shall give it a try.. Thanks!!

Comment: what's happening is that:    1. Main.java calls OAuthHandler servlet(which makes the Http request using parameters) and the server responses with a html form where the client has to enter email and password and grant access to the app. So this html form needs a browser to be displayed so I have to use the method Desktop.getDesktop().browse() right?? or is there any other way?